# How to use for loop instead of foreach loop?

Tags: c#, optimization, loops, for-loop, foreach

how can i implement this foreach loop with for loop? because i heard that for loop is much faster than foreach loop.

```
   foreach (RV item in gridview.SelectedItems.ToList())
   {
        R req= db.Requests.Single(x => x.Id == item.Id);
        ...
   }
```

Comment: That's a trivial `for` loop; I don't see your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You heard incorrectly.
`for` loops are not much faster than `foreach` loops.
In fact, for some collections, `foreach` loops are much faster than `for` loops.

`ToList()` is slower than either of them.

If you really want to make your code faster, you should use an O(n) LINQ join instead of the O(n<sup>2</sup>) `Single()` call.

Comment: When does `foreach loop` faster then `for loop`?

Comment: @gdoron: When using a linked list as an `IList<T>`.

Comment: Can you please explain why, or provide a link?

Comment: @gdoron: The indexer of a linked list of O(n) since it needs to start from the beginning every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.SelectedItems.Count(); i++)
{
    R req = db.Requests.Single(x => x.ID == (gridview.SelectedItems(i) as RV).Id);
    ...
}
```

Although I doubt there will be any noticeable performance gain.

Comment: There will be an (immeasurable) performance loss from the `Count()`s.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in converting your selected items to a list, if you are enumerating them with foreach anyway. Also a for loop requires you to call ToList, which internally uses a foreach!

I do not know, if your o/r-mapper can cope with `Contains`. If it does try this:

```
var items = db.Requests.Where(x => gridview.SelectedItems.Contains(x.Id));
```

This will reduce the number of database requests. This is where time gets lost, not in the foreach!